# Unable to adb pull androidTest created file from emulator in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

Inside my androidTest I create a custom text file

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TestResults");
    logFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "result.txt");

    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and during the test run I write some custom data there. When I run test locally on the emulator, I can see the file created and I can pull it using

[image]

```
adb pull /sdcard/TestResults/result.txt
```

But when I run the same test inside Jenkins build step

```
echo pulling test result file
cd %LocalDir%\Android\sdk\platform-tools

adb.exe pull /sdcard/TestResults/result.txt D:\ANDROID_TEST_DATA\
```

and try to pull the file, I get:

```
pulling test result file    
adb: error: remote object '/sdcard/TestResults/result.txt' does not exist
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
    [android] Stopping Android emulator
```

Any ideas, how this could be fixed?

**Update**

Also tried paths:

```
/storage/emulated/0/TestResults/result.txt
/mnt/sdcard/TestResults/result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
adb.exe pull /mnt/sdcard/TestResults/result.txt D:\ANDROID_TEST_DATA\
```

Comment: @insomnium_ guess you'd have to launch the `cmd` with `Run as Administrator` (as a manual test, to ensure to path would work with elevated permissions).

Comment: and then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413261/run-batch-file-as-administrator-on-jenkins